# Replace Output Column Values Within a Range to "True"

Tags: r, mcmc, r-mice

I am trying to write a function involving the MICE package, and want to specify whether the Markov chains within the imputed dataset have converged by the criteria of the Gelman and Rubin statistic used in Rhat.mice (from package "miceadds") by replacing all values between .999 and 1.001 in the Rhat.M.imp and Rhat.Var.imp with "TRUE". For reference, here is a sample output of Rhat.mice:

```
> testagain<- Rhat.mice(ini)
>     variable  MissProp Rhat.M.imp Rhat.Var.imp
>1        agep  5.681818   1.015537     1.021311
>2       alcgp 18.181818   1.002916     1.007297
>3       tobgp 17.045455   1.026634     1.042405
>4     disease  1.136364   1.014819           NA
```

And here is the code I tried to use (I got the error Error: unexpected '<' in "testagain$Rhat.M.imp[(0.999

```
 testagain$Rhat.M.imp[(0.999<testagain$Rhat.M.imp<1.001]<- TRUE
```

I would like an output like the following

```
1.015537 
1.002916
1.026634
1.014819
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just found a function that worked:  x<- ifelse(between(testagain$Rhat.M.imp,.999,1.001),TRUE,NA).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to create a new variable instead, but if you want to go on this way, you can coerce the `Rhat.M.imp` into a character variable.

```
df <- read.table(text = t, header = T, strip.white = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(
  Rhat.M.imp = case_when(1 < Rhat.M.imp & Rhat.M.imp < 1.01~as.character(TRUE), TRUE~as.character(Rhat.M.imp))
)

#   variable MissProp Rhat.M.imp Rhat.Var.imp
# 1     agep    5.682   1.015537        1.021
# 2    alcgp   18.182       TRUE        1.007
# 3    tobgp   17.045   1.026634        1.042
# 4  disease    1.136   1.014819           NA
```

Here is the data set.

```
t <- "variable  MissProp Rhat.M.imp Rhat.Var.imp
        agep  5.681818   1.015537     1.021311
       alcgp 18.181818   1.002916     1.007297
       tobgp 17.045455   1.026634     1.042405
     disease  1.136364   1.014819           NA"

df <- read.table(text = t, header = T, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I see your point about creating a new variable being easier, now. I will try that, first.